# Changing List to As.Numeric

Tags: r, list

I found some data in (x,y) table format on the internet and I want to use it simply for a t-test. I copied and pasted from the internet, and it looked like this on R

```
20.79  194.5  23.89  200.9  28.49  209.5 
20.79  194.3  23.99  201.1  27.76  208.6 
22.40  197.9  24.02  201.4  29.04  210.7 
22.67  198.4  24.01  201.3  29.88  211.9 
23.15  199.4  25.14  203.6  30.06  212.2 
23.35  199.9  26.57  204.6
```

I want to make it into a data.frame where by the first column (of mostly values in the 20's) is `x`, and the second column (with values 190-220) are `y`. I have played around with it, but currently I'm stuck with a list, and when I try

```
   as.numeric(mylist)
```

it gives me an error message that reads

```
"Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' "
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its useful to read numeric elements with `scan` and then to configure them as a matrix based on the ordering of their sequence.

```
> inp <- scan(text="20.79  194.5  23.89  200.9  28.49  209.5 
+ 20.79  194.3  23.99  201.1  27.76  208.6 
+ 22.40  197.9  24.02  201.4  29.04  210.7 
+ 22.67  198.4  24.01  201.3  29.88  211.9 
+ 23.15  199.4  25.14  203.6  30.06  212.2 
+ 23.35  199.9  26.57  204.6")
Read 34 items
> M.in <- matrix(inp, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
> M.in
       [,1]  [,2]
 [1,] 20.79 194.5
 [2,] 23.89 200.9
 [3,] 28.49 209.5
 [4,] 20.79 194.3
 [5,] 23.99 201.1
 [6,] 27.76 208.6
 [7,] 22.40 197.9
 [8,] 24.02 201.4
 [9,] 29.04 210.7
[10,] 22.67 198.4
[11,] 24.01 201.3
[12,] 29.88 211.9
[13,] 23.15 199.4
[14,] 25.14 203.6
[15,] 30.06 212.2
[16,] 23.35 199.9
[17,] 26.57 204.6
```

Now you can do:

```
> t.test(M.in[,1], M.in[,2])

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  M.in[, 1] and M.in[, 2] 
t = -112.7824, df = 24.18, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -181.1483 -174.6400 
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 25.05882 202.95294
```

You could have used `as.data.frame` to convert `M.in` to a dataframe.) If you were convinced that these were segregated into groups of six, you could access them using:

```
first6 <- M.in[ 1:6, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass text to `read.table` directly; the complicating thing is that you also need `fill=NA` because of the missing values.

```
d <- read.table(text="20.79  194.5  23.89  200.9  28.49  209.5 
20.79  194.3  23.99  201.1  27.76  208.6 
22.40  197.9  24.02  201.4  29.04  210.7 
22.67  198.4  24.01  201.3  29.88  211.9 
23.15  199.4  25.14  203.6  30.06  212.2 
23.35  199.9  26.57  204.6", fill=NA)
names(d)[1:2] <- c("x", "y")

#       x     y    V3    V4    V5    V6
# 1 20.79 194.5 23.89 200.9 28.49 209.5
# 2 20.79 194.3 23.99 201.1 27.76 208.6
# 3 22.40 197.9 24.02 201.4 29.04 210.7
# 4 22.67 198.4 24.01 201.3 29.88 211.9
# 5 23.15 199.4 25.14 203.6 30.06 212.2
# 6 23.35 199.9 26.57 204.6    NA    NA
```